# ¿Cómo puedo crear una función en c con parametros y no devuelva error al no pasarle algún parámetro?

Tags: c

Quiero crear una función dónde le pase dos parámetros de tipo int, y que cuando llame a la función y solo le pase un parámetro no me genere un error por no haberle pasado el segundo parámetro.
Ejemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int suma(int x, int y){
return x+y;
}

void main(){
printf("%d",suma(4));
}
```

Como haría para que no me genere error, y que además si no le pase el parámetro "y" este se sustituya por 0

Answer (score 2):

Siento decirte que en C no sé puede.

Lo más cercano que puedes hacer es definir una nueva función:

```
int suma_uno(int x){
    return x;
}
```

O si prefieres, usa una macro (no se puede llamar igual que la función):

```
#define suma_1(x) suma(x, 0)
```

En C++ podrías usar parámetros con valores por defecto. Así:

```
int suma(int x = 0, int y = 0){
    return x + y;
}
```

A tener en cuenta: **los parámetros con valores predeterminados solo pueden estar al final.**

Por ejemplo, esto es válido:

```
int suma(int x, int y = 0){
    return x + y;
}
```

Pero esto no:

```
int suma(int x = 0, int y){
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Al intentar lo que me sugeriste me da error

Comment: Esa sintaxis no es válida en C. El C no admite parámetros opcionales. Lo más parecido serían las funciones variádicas, pero son un horror.